# Can Danish policemen refuse to provide ID when asked?

Tags: law, law-enforcement, denmark

This [Guardian article](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/jan/27/scandinavian-miracle-brutal-truth-denmark-norway-sweden?CMP=share_btn_fb)  makes the (unsourced) claim that (emphasis mine):

> There is more than a whiff of the police state about the fact that **Danish policeman refuse to display ID numbers and can refuse to give their names**.

Can Danish policemen legally refuse to display their ID numbers when asked? Is this actually legal under Danish law?

Comment: If you do not trust the guardian, whom do you trust?

Comment: @sim Many conmen pretend to be policemen, so widespread refusal to validate identities by actual policemen would make these conmen impossible to spot.

Comment: This quote could also mean that the officers aren't casually displaying their ID numbers but will reveal them when asked to.

Comment: Related: [Danish police to wear ID numbers under new plan](http://www.thelocal.dk/20141002/danish-police-to-wear-id-numbers-proposal), Oct 2014.

Comment: Related question: does Denmark not have policewomen?

Comment: @Sim the piece was written by someone who has just published a book, apparently. The author may be tempted to bend the truth in this opinion piece to get good sales.